# Side-effects and top-level expressions in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, side-effects

I am in trouble with ocaml.

I want to make a function that will increment my counter every time I call it and concat my vargen string with the counter number and return this new string.

What I did without success is:

```
let (counter : int ref) = ref 0;;
let (vargen : string) = "_t";;
let tmp = incr counter;ref (vargen ^ string_of_int !counter);;
Printf.printf "%s\n" !tmp;;
Printf.printf "%s\n" !tmp;;
Printf.printf "%s\n" !tmp;;
Printf.printf "%s\n" !tmp;;
```

But my output are always:

```
_t1
_t1
_t1
_t1
```

And what my output should be:

```
    _t0
    _t1
    _t2
    _t3
```

Any ideas to solve my problem guyz?

Thks all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write `let tmp = ref foo`, the expression `foo` is evaluated once, to produce a value which is stored in the reference. Accessing the reference returns this value, without re-evaluating the original expression.

The way to provoke re-evaluation is to use a function instead: if you write a function `(fun () -> foo)`, this is a value: it is returned as is, passed to functions, stored in references. And each time you apply an argument to this value, the expression `foo` is evaluated.

Clément's solution is good. The idea of

```
let counter =
  let count = ref (-1) in
  fun () -> incr count; !count
```

Is that the reference is allocated once, but incremented each time the function `fun () -> incr count; !count` is called. Having the reference local to the function avoids some of the pitfall of global variables. You can think of it as a "static variable" of the function `counter`, only it is a natural result of OCaml scoping and evaluation rules and not an additional, function-specific concept.

You can even write an even more general `vargen` generator, that creates fresh, independent counters each time it's called:

```
let make_vargen prefix =
   let count = ref (-1) in
   fun () ->
     incr count;
     prefix ^ string_of_int !count

let fresh_t = make_vargen "t"
let () = print_endline (fresh_t ())  (* t0 *)
let () = print_endline (fresh_t ())  (* t1 *)
let fresh_u = make_vargen "u"
let () = print_endline (fresh_u ())  (* u0 *)
let () = print_endline (fresh_t ())  (* t2 *)
let () = print_endline (fresh_u ())  (* u1 *)
```

Comment: Very good explanation, now I understood why my program isnt working.

Answer (score 3):

Since `tmp` is a value, it is executed once. Changing it into a function should make the counter increase each time `tmp` is invoked.

Furthermore, you could return `string` instead of `string ref` for simplicity:

```
let counter: int ref = ref (-1);;
let vargen: string = "_t";;

// tmp now is a function
let tmp() = incr counter; vargen ^ string_of_int !counter;;

Printf.printf "%s\n" (tmp());;
Printf.printf "%s\n" (tmp());;
Printf.printf "%s\n" (tmp());;
Printf.printf "%s\n" (tmp());;
```

Comment: Verry good, and this solution suits perfectly in my problem, solving it and some others that I have.

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
let tmp = 
  let counter = ref 0 in
  (fun () -> incr counter; vargen ^ (string_of_int !counter))
```

Call the function using `tmp ()`, and change 0 to -1 if you want the counter to start at 0.

Comment: Very compact form of the pad's solution, it helped very much. Thks

Answer (score 1):

If you need the counter to be optionally read without incrementing it, you can add an argument:

```
let counter =
  let count = ref (-1) in
    fun do_incr -> if do_incr then begin incr count end; !count;;
```

Using it like:

```
# counter true;;
- : int = 0
# counter true;;
- : int = 1
# counter true;;
- : int = 2
# counter false;;
- : int = 2
# counter false;;
- : int = 2
# counter true;;
- : int = 3
```